# Replacing string using perl containing $ sign with other string containing $ sign and bash variable

Tags: bash, perl, replace

I want to replace some strings in files that contain $ signs with an other string that also contains $ signs plus the value from a bash variable. The file contains strings like the following.

```
$Rev: 12345 $ $Author: 12345 $
```

Lets say I have a bash variable called `i` containing the string `foo`. I now want to replace `$Rev: 12345 $` with `$Rev: $i $`. I  tried using sed but since sed doesn't support non-greedy regex I switched to perl. Perl works fine when I don't use any bash variables.

```
# cat file
$Rev: 12345 $ $Author: 12345 $
# perl -p -i -e 's;\$Rev:.*?\$;\$Rev: test \$;g' file
# cat file
$Rev: test $ $Author: 12345 $
```

But no matter how I escape the $ signs in the command, I cannot get it to work with a bash variable.

```
# cat file
$Rev: 12345 $ $Author: 12345 $
# i="foo"
# echo $i
foo
# perl -p -i -e "s;\$Rev:.*?\$;\$Rev: $i \$;g" file
Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s;$Rev:.*?$;$Rev: foo $;g"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
# perl -p -i -e "s;\\$Rev:.*?\\$;\$Rev: $i \\$;g" file
# cat file
$Rev: foo $ $Author: foo $
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: These auto-updated version comments were thought to be a good idea back in the RCS and CSV days, but experience taught us that they were not.

Comment: Use single quotes around Perl scripts in Bash.

Comment: Why do you set a bash variable to use as replacement in Perl code? Do you just not know how to set variables in Perl? Or is this a variable that will be used in other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `$i` outside the quotes entirely:

```
perl -pi -e 's;\$Rev:.*?\$;\$Rev: '$i' \$;g' file
#           ^---------------------^  ^-----^
```

Or, you could `export` the variable to sub-processes, and access it via the `%ENV` hash in Perl:

```
export i="foo"
perl -pi -e 's;\$Rev:.*?\$;\$Rev: $ENV{i} \$;g' file
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use a Perl variable inside Perl, not let the shell expand its variable into Perl code.

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/^\$Rev:.*?\$/\$Rev: $i \$/g' -s -- -i="$i" file
```

You can then use single quotes around the code which makes it much easier to backslash stuff correctly.

The `-s` tells Perl to accept `-var=val` switches and set Perl variable `$var` to `val` before running the code.

Comment: I like this better than my suggestion.

Comment: This is in fact a cleaner solution but it will also output the replaced string. I could rederict the output to /dev/null like so "perl -pe 's;\$Rev:.*?\$;\$Rev: $i \$;g' -s -- -i="$i" file> /dev/null 2>&1" but that seems unnecessarily complicated compared to @JimDavis solution. It propably doesn't matter which one I use. What do you think?

Comment: @Chullian What do you mean "it will output the replaced string"? Are you talking about the fact that choroba left out the `-i` (in-place edit) switch?

Comment: @Chullian: Updated to include the `-i`.